# vgg_19 slim model a frozen.pb graph?

Tags: tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-slim

I downloaded the vgg_19_2016_08_28.tar.gz and extracted a vgg-19.pb graph. I am using this for tf2onnx. However, this seems to have some dynamic parameters and hence tf2onnx if failing. I want to check if the vgg-19.pb is a frozen graph, if not how can I get a frozen vgg_19.pb graph?

Same question for tensorflow_inception_graph - inception_v3_2016_08_28.tar.gz

Same question for resnet - resnet_v1_50_2016_08_28.tar.gz

All downloaded from here - https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#pre-trained-models

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51322381/tensorflow-model-saving-and-loading/51324195#51324195) for loading a `pb` file.

Answer (score 0):

To convert TF models to ONNX you need to freeze the graph. The TensorFlow tool to freeze the graph is https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py

For example

```
 python -m tensorflow.python.tools.freeze_graph \
   --input_graph=my_checkpoint_dir/graphdef.pb \
   --input_binary=true \
   --output_node_names=output \
   --input_checkpoint=my_checkpoint_dir \
   --output_graph=tests/models/fc-layers/frozen.pb
```

To find the inputs and outputs for the TensorFlow graph the model developer will know or you can consult TensorFlow's summarize_graph tool (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms), for example:

```
summarize_graph --in_graph=tests/models/fc-layers/frozen.pb
```

Comment: The pretrained models link do not have checkpoints. They only have the .pb file

Comment: The .pb file should be fine. The `input_graph` for the `tensorflow.python.tools.freeze_graph` is in the format of .pb. You could use .pb file to freeze the graph. The tool which I mentioned in the answer worked for me.

Comment: For input checkpoint provide the path to ckpt file. For example                                
  --input_checkpoint=model.ckpt-8361242

Comment: The pretrained models link does not have checkpoint. freeze_graph needs both .pb and the .ckpt and the link only has the .pb.

Comment: Hi, I downloaded the `inception_v1_2016_08_28.tar.gz` and extracted using 7zip twice and was able to get the ckpt file. How did u get the pb file?